# Computer seems to hang after successful login via lightdm

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, login, lightdm

I sucessfully installed Xubuntu 16.04.1 on my computer. When switched on, it shows the login screen of lightdm and I can enter my credentials.

However, after any window has vanished and only the background image is shown, nothing happens anymore.
I cannot bring up any menu. Mouse clicks and key strokes do nothing and no window or panel appears.

When I log in on a console, I can kill the X process and after that, lightdm will reappear. Logging in again will show the same behavior.

When lightdm is shown, I can log in on the console and use startx to bring up a working instance of X where everything is as I expected (Menu and panel available, programs can be started and used ...).

Neither the lightdm log file nor the X log file did not show any suspicious entries.

Is there something I can do about it or check for further information?

Thank you.