# LightDM login freezes after successful authentication

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

I can't seem to log in on Ubuntu 16.04.4 with lightdm, even though authentication is successful. I am able to use the console just fine, but I need to be able to use graphical browsers from time to time.

This is an excerpt of my `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`:

```
[+3.56s] DEBUG: Session pid=8307: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+3.56s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+10.81s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+10.83s] DEBUG: Session pid=8307: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+10.83s] DEBUG: User x authorized
[+10.83s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session unity8-mir
[+10.83s] DEBUG: Using VT 8
[+10.83s] DEBUG: DisplayServer: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/unity-system-compositor.log
[+10.83s] DEBUG: Launching process 8311: /usr/sbin/unity-suystem-compositor.sleep --file '/run/mir_socket' --from-dm-fd 12 --to-dm-fd 21 --vt 8
[+10.83s] DEBUG: DisplayServer: Waiting for system compositor for 60s
[+10.97s] DEBUG: DisplayServer: Compositor closed communication channel
[+10.97s] DEBUG: Process 8311 exited with return value 0
```

For some reason, the compositor is closing the communication channel. Other users can log in to the graphical interface.

Has anyone encountered similar issues? It's not that [lightdm redirects](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709468/lightdm-fails-to-login-and-redirects). Nor does it [hang the computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815077/computer-seems-to-hang-after-successful-login-via-lightdm), although `sudo service lightdm restart` from an alternate console lets me repeat the error every time.